# Math.floor math.random (what is the + min doing)

Tags: javascript

```
var min = 1; 
var max = 50;
var array = []; 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); 

for (var i=0; i<randomNumber; i++) {
    array.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
}

console.log(array);
```

For this can we explain what the + min is doing? What would be the difference if we took out the + min and just did Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)); ?

Comment: Try it out, and observe the results...

Answer (score 3):

The addition of `min` shifts the range of values you can get out of the expression from [0, `max - min`] up to [min, max].

Answer (score 2):

We know that `Math.floor(Math.round()*6);` returns a value in the range [0,6) or 0,1,2,3,4,5. Here we get 6 numbers out.

Let's say we want to generate numbers from 5 to 10 inclusive. We need to know how many numbers are there.  `var min = 5; var max = 10;` If we list them out, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and count them we see that there are 6 total numbers. We know from before that we're going to have to multiply by 6 in order to get 6 numbers out.

If you do `max - min` you get 5 which is 1 short. `max - min` gives you the distance from 5 to 10. You always have to add 1 to that if you want the total amount of numbers.

That gives us the expression `max - min + 1` and putting that into the formula:

`Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));`

At this point the formula can generate the correct amount of numbers but they always start at 0 because the range from Math.random starts from 0.

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4,  5 // What we have
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 // What we want
```

Notice that if we add 5 to all the numbers in the first row, we'll get the second row. 5 is what our min value is in the example.

So if we add the min value onto the end of our formula, it will shift all the numbers over to the ones we want.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```